# Html in jquery string

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need the best way to parse the html from the string, I have tried .html(); and it does not work. I need it on cdata variable.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var anOpen = [];
var oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable();

$('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    var nTr = this;
    var i = $.inArray(nTr, anOpen);
    var cdata = this.cells[1];

    console.log(cdata);
    if (i == -1) {
        $(this).addClass('row_selected');
        var nDetailsRow = oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr, 1), 'details');
        $('div.innerDetails', nDetailsRow).slideDown();
        anOpen.push(nTr);
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
        $('div.innerDetails', $(nTr).next()[0]).slideUp(function () {
            oTable.fnClose(nTr);
            anOpen.splice(i, 1);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Where in the code given does the querystring parsing occur?

Comment: Add comments to your code please.

Comment: when i console.log(cdata) i am getting <td class>infotextblah</td> I need the html code out and just the infotextblah.

Comment: You're looking to strip out HTML? See the second half of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use `$(this)` instead of the javascript `this`. Just for coherence, try using jQuery at most when you can achieve it with jQuery.

Using jQuery you could do

```
$myTd = $(this).find("td").get(1) ;
```

`$myTd.text()` gives your text here. See http://api.jquery.com/text/

Using javascript, you want to get the inner content of your td tag... so `this.cells[1].innerHTML` returns the innerHTML of your tag, which in your case is your text.

Comment: I am a little confused on why the .find, is there not a way to specify the second column of data without the html? When I do $(this).find("td").first() I get a entire object back. I do not have a tdclass assigned to that column.

Comment: Oh sorry, you want the second td. Didn't pay attention. Well, your call to this.cells[1] returns the td itself also. If you want a javascript solution, since you used javascript on this line, I would use this.cells[1].innerHtml.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableCellElement> has no method 'innerHtml'

Comment: innerHTML sorry. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

`html()` is the way to go if you're trying to fetch the data from an element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var html_str = $("#foo").html();
    alert("Your HTML is: " + html_str); 
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/4q6AZ/

If you're looking to strip out all HTML tags, you may consider:

```
var html_string = '<h1>Test</h1><p>A paragraph with a <a href="link">link</a></p>';
var regex = /<(\/?)[a-zA-Z0-9][^>]*>/g;
var stripped = html_string.replace(regex, '');
$("#result").html(stripped);
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6q2j/5/

Answer (score 0):

Jquery `.text()` will send you back the text and not the HTML elements. http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Yes but his td just contains text anyway. That won't help. He's not even using jQuery to get his text right now.